# Passing argument to java's constructor method of type List

Tags: java, constructor

I have constructor method that looks like the following:

```
public Profile(List<PointGrade> g)
```

If i want to call that method in different class, how do I pass argument of type list?

Comment: Are you asking how to create an instance of List<PointGrade> and fill it with some data?

Comment: yes I would like to create instance of that class and pass parameters

Answer (score 1):

You should create an istance of the object `Profile` like this:

```
  List<PointGrade> list = new ArrayList<PointGrade>();
  Profile profile =new Profile(list);
```

And you can use this istance maybe like this:

```
     profile.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List< PointGrade> g=new ArrayList< PointGrade>();

XXX.Profile(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Profile profile = new Profile(new List<PointGrade>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of List:

```
List<PointGrade> list = new ArrayList<PointGrade>();
```

Populate it with some data (if you don't want to pass empty list):

```
PointGrade pg = new PointGrade();

//fill PointGrade fields you need

list.add(pg);
```

And then pass it to a constructor:

```
Profile profile = new Profile(list);
```